# Multiply matrix by array element-wise on numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

What I want is really simple but I can't figure out how to do it on numpy.

I have the following matrix:

```
M = [[1, 1, 1],
     [1, 1, 1],
     [1, 1, 1]]
```

And this array:

```
A = [1, 2, 3]
```

I want to multiply the matrix with each element on the array on a way to produce:

```
[[[1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1],
  [1, 1, 1]],
 [[2, 2, 2],
  [2, 2, 2],
  [2, 2, 2]],
 [[3, 3, 3],
  [3, 3, 3],
  [3, 3, 3]]]
```

without any for loops, I want just a numpy function.

Comment: I’m not sure about “without any loops” as you need each element of the array; hence a loop.  Something similar to `np.array([M*i for i in A])` perhaps?

Comment: You have an iterative process; you must have some sort of loop, even if it's implicit.  Note that this is *not* a typical NumPy broadcasting operation: you're not replicating `A` to the size of `M` for element-wise operations.  Rather, you want your output shape to be the product of the two sizes.

Comment: What I **can** do is pass M with the same shape as A (copying on the third axis) and apply element-wise operations. I just can't use a python `for` loop.

Comment: And I take it back!  There are two brilliant solutions below.  Learned something new today!  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [146]: M = np.ones((3,3),int)                                                                     
In [147]: M                                                                                          
Out[147]: 
array([[1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1]])
In [148]: A = np.array([1,2,3])
```

broadcasted multiplication does this:

```
In [149]: A[:,None,None]*M                                                                           
Out[149]: 
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3]]])
```

`A` is changed to (3,1,1); `M` is automatically broadcast to (1,3,3), together (3,3,3)

Comment: By the way, if I change M to 4 x 4, why the same code doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

Using `einsum`

```
np.einsum('ij,k->kji', M, A)
```

---

```
array([[[1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 1]],

       [[2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2],
        [2, 2, 2]],

       [[3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3],
        [3, 3, 3]]])
```